# I don't want neither Vs. I want neither

Tags: multiple-negation

If I don't want a paper or a pen. What's the right way to say it out of these two choices?

> I **do not** want **neither** a paper nor a pen.

or

> I want **neither** a paper nor a pen.

I believe that **do not + neither** is double negatives, but I'm not sure about that and I'd like to ensure it before I'm going to use it in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may correctly say:

"I do not want either paper or a pen."

You may also correctly say:

"I want neither paper nor a pen."

What is not a correct way to say what you want to convey is:

"I do not want neither paper nor a pen."